# Why doesn't logrotate's filename globbing pick up files with spaces in their names?

Tags: logrotate

If I specify `*bar* {}` logrotate will match `foo-bar.log` but not `foo bar.log`.

From what I have read, logrotate's globbing should behave like shell globbing, so to test I have run `ls *bar*`. However, this prints out both `foo-bar.log` *and* `foo bar.log` so I do not believe they are the using same glob matching algorithm.

How do I write a logrotate wildcard glob that will match files with spaces in their names?

```
$ logrotate -v
logrotate 3.8.7 - Copyright (C) 1995-2001 Red Hat, Inc.
```

Comment: Spaces in file names can cause many headaches, if possible you might want to reconsider the name if you have control over that

Comment: I will not permit `logrotate` to dictate how I structure my files.

Comment: It's not just `logrotate`, this is probably just the first headache, though you'll likely be able to make it work, I suggest it isn't worth the effort, but it's not my effort so if you think it's worth it good luck to you

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions Even in the shell this'll give you problems unless you quote the variable name everywhere (which few shell programs bother to do). Space is one of the characters in `$IFS`. "The only thing giving me a headache is you." That was uncalled for. Especially given how polite he was being about your beginner mistake.

Comment: @ParthianShot Your beginner mistake is assuming I am a beginner and the liberty I take with spaces is a mistake. Let me assure you, though I should not have to, that I know exactly what I am doing when I introduce spaces into my filenames; that I do so deliberately and that it causes me absolutely no problems in any other scenario because in all other cases the way this should be handled is well documented and easy to avoid pitfalls when one follows the prescribed conventions for dealing with such file names. Logrotate, however, poses an exception with its poorly documented handling of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Renouf's statement is correct. Spaces in filenames is bound to cause you problems and if you don't either account for that in your code or change how you use filenames then you are going to create more headaches for yourself.

More detailed explanations of why this is a bad idea are [here](https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names).

That said, if you read the [man](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) pages for `logrotate` you will see in the third paragraph it states,

> Note that the double quotes around the first filename at  the  beginning  of  this  section  allows logrotate  to rotate logs with spaces in the name.

That part you seem to be aware of but what you also need to do is account for the space in the filename.

The next sentence in the man pages is,

> Normal shell quoting rules apply, with ’, ", and \ characters supported.

So you have to escape the space with you do with quotes, but your wildcard causes a problem. For the wildcard to work it must be outside the quotes.

An example of how to do this is available on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156534/bash-script-error-with-strings-with-paths-that-have-spaces-and-wildcards).

Since you have a custom naming convention for your log files I will assume that you know the part of your filename before the space.

So you can create an array

```
files=( /dir/subdir/filename\ morefilename*.log )
```

Then run log rotate telling the files are "${files[@]}".

If you have other log files that do not have spaces in their names repeat this process.

You can see why wildcards in filenames is a very bad idea when you are scripting.

Please do some research on escaping special characters and be sure to read the manual.